# Contact Form only sending message body but ignoring other fields

Tags: php, html

Please guys am in deep trouble, i have being sweating hard for the past 24 hours, i have this contact form which i uploaded to my server, but the sad part is that, it is only sending the message body to my email, ignoring the other fields like name field, email field and phone number. I am tired of staring at the php code, i feel everything is ok but the code is not working as expected, please help me.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phone_error = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
      $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["url"])) {
    $url_error = "";
  } else {
    $url = test_input($_POST["url"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
      $url_error = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'emmanuelgbnn23@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<?php include('form_process.php'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css">
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>" tabindex="1" autofocus>
      <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2">
      <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="text" name="phone" value="<?= $phone ?>" tabindex="3">
      <span class="error"><?= $phone_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Web Site starts with http://" type="text" name="url" value="<?= $url ?>" tabindex="4" >
      <span class="error"><?= $url_error ?></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea value="<?= $message ?>" name="message" tabindex="5">
      </textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What you get in `print_r($_POST)` ?

Comment: Replace `if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){`  with `if ($name_error == '' && $email_error == '' && $phone_error == '' && $url_error == '' ){`

Comment: Please i don't get the question

Comment: @ Gunaseelan i tried it but it did not work

Comment: After the `foreach`, check  `$message_body` value by `var_dump($message_body)`.

Comment: @PPP put print_r($_POST) and are you getting other fields

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong variable `$message` in your mail() function. Since you are appending values into `$message_body` replace `$message` with `$message_body` in your script and try again.

```
<?php 

    // define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name_error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $phone_error = "Phone is required";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["url"])) {
        $url_error = "";
    } else {
        $url = test_input($_POST["url"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
        if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url)) {
            $url_error = "Invalid URL"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $to = 'emmanuelgbnn23@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
            $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
            $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
        }
    }

}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: $message have data , the problem is with and operator in if condition

Comment: Please note that his issue is "Contact Form only sending message body but ignoring other fields".

Comment: @PPP Are you getting value in $message_body ? Just print and check.

Comment: The script is still sending just the message field but ignoring other fields, guys please help.

Comment: Please am a php beginner, don't really get what you are asking me to do

Comment: Oh my God thanks is finally working. Thanks @dhi_m you are a magician, thanks everyone. Oh my! a huge relieve

Comment: I hope to be an expert programmer one day and help others. I owe all of you a beer.

Comment: One more question please

Comment: Didn't get the question. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code

```
if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' )
```

To this

```
if ($name_error == '' && $email_error == '' && $phone_error == '' && $url_error == '' )
```

Learn php operators [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: So what is the difference between `&&` and `and`? Other than them having a different precedence, which doesn't matter in this specific case.